# VS Static Linking with Python Library and wxWidgets

Tags: python, c++, wxwidgets, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Case:
I am using VS 2019 to build a C++ project into `.exe` build, the program is based on 2 libraries the main one is `wxWidgets` and a wrapper C++ library around Python, this library namely: `matplotlibcpp` its a wrapper around the original Python `matploblib` library. My `.exe` program works fine on multiple computer (in deployment) without firing any missing `.dll` files without the use of `matplotlibcpp`, the last step was using `matplotlibcpp` to plot. I am aware of the differences between Release and Debug Build modes and Build Architectures (Win32(x86) and x64)

Environment:

- VS++19, Project Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset = v142
- C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Library = `$(WXWIN)\include;$(WXWIN)\include\msvc;C:\<Name>\Softwares\Python39-32\include;C:\<Name>\Softwares\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include`
- C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library = Multi-Threaded DLL (/MD)
- C/C++ -> Advanced -> Omit Default Library Name = No
- Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories = `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib;C:\<Name>\Softwares\Python39-32\libs`

Problem:
Deploying the `release` build of my program fired missing `python39.dll` file, I tried these solutions I found.

1. Dispatched the program with all `.dll` files from Python installation location (release dlls not the debug ones) the result was: the program started but crashed when clicking a button that fires an event that use a method scoped to `matplotlibcpp`.
2. In Visual Studio Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Advanced -> Use of MFC is set to "Use MFC in a Static Library", C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> Multi-Threaded(/MT) resulted 3 types of error:

- `47 Unresolved externals`
- `mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in cApp.obj <Project Name>`
- `unresolved external symbol __imp___fdopen <Project Name>`
  like 334 errors, resetting Use of MFC  to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" removes the `47 unresolved externals` error.

3. Repeating solution "2." with addition of C/C++ -> Advanced -> Omit Default Library Name to "Yes (/Zl)" reduced the error to 264 where:

- `263 Unresolved externals`
- `mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in cApp.obj <Project Name>`

Obviously the third type of errors form "2." where transferred to `unresolved externals` error.

Investigation: I revisited the way I built each library. `wxWidgets` was built using Microsoft Visual Studio Solutions `.sln` files and the guide said that in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories "($WXWIN)\lib\vc_lib" helps in statically linking the library so back before applying the 3 solutions, did I built my `.exe` program linked statically to `wxWidgets` but dynamically linked to `matplotlibcpp`?? I installed the `matplotlibcpp` library using `vcpkg` tool method.

I hope that I understood the problem quite well because I am a beginner at software development and deployment, so I barely understand the difference between Static libraries `.lib` and Dynamic Libraries `.dll`

Resources:

- wxWidgets installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOIbK4bJKS8&t=1092s
- maplotlibcpp repo: https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp

Comment: `Deploying the release build of my program fired missing python39.dll file` Are you trying to deploy the program or just run it from MSVC? Are you sure that the `mathplotlibcpp was built with the same settings as wxWidgets and you software? I would try to build that yourself keeping in mind that everything needs to match, especially the RTT settings and Dynamic vs Static linking settings.

Comment: Ask on the mathplotlibcpp forum about how to build the library if you get stuck. My guess is that you are trying to mix dynamic/static (RTT) options and getting the crashes because of that.

Comment: @Igor I am not trying to mix between static and dynamic, I am trying to have a working program running on any machine(Windows) statically linked. I am not sure what you mean by "mathplotlibcpp was built with the same settings as wxWidgets and you software" cause I am not sure how `vcpkg`  built matplotlibcpp, I just applied the git/clone commands used in the Readme.

Comment: this is exactly my point. Most likely that package was build as dll (dynamic library) and you are trying to link it statically. You should build it yourself or rebuild everything dynamically linked.

Comment: @Igor Thank You, probably I won't be doing such thing considering my limited skills and I very short on time so I will try to find another way around plotting in wxWidgets, Thank you once again.

Comment: as a test you can try to build dynamic linking configuration and see if my presumption is correct. Just keep in mind that you will need to copy all the dlls in the folder where the program is for the test purposes and later when distributing have a dedicated place for all those dll. Just make sure the installer updates the $PATH variable with that dedicated place.